# Android Devices Problems with OpenGL ES GL 11

Tags: android, opengl-es, device

I tested my app on some Android 2.1 and 2.2 devices. So I think that they support OpenGL ES 1.1
But on some devices I had problems whit my app. I get an unsupported operation exception means the device does not support the GL 11 interface. Is this a hardware problem? Are there some possibilities to avoid this problem?

Thanks,
Mijat

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exact error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the exception I get is not useful. Because I pick a peace of code from the net, and this one checks the extension I temporally need with all extension from the interface GL 11. 
And if there is no agreement, the code throws a exception. 
The Problem case is, that I have an app and I tried in on the HTC Desire and some model of LG. It works great, but on a third device which works on Android 2.2 I get this exception. 
Means OpenGL ES GL11 isn’t covered.

Comment: I actually know that some devices have problems with the ES extension 1.1. 
And the reason must be in the hardware…
Motorola Milestone as example. Supports OpenGL ES 1.0 and 2.0 but not 1.1 or 2.1 . 
Es 1.1 is needed for the off screen buffer if you want to select your object by color.

Answer (score 0):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html :

> Finally, note that though Android does include some basic support for OpenGL ES 1.1, the support is not complete, and should not be relied upon at this time.

Pretty much answers the question.